# ES6 Javascript Shorthand create property only if it's truthy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have

```
const {status} = req.body;
```

I want to include **status** in my query object only if the status has truthy value(other than `null` or `undefined` or **empty string**),

Currently I'm doing this,

```
const query = {
   otherCondition: 1,
};

if (status) {
  query.status = status;
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this using if clause using ES6 Object shorthand ?

If I use,

```
const query = {
   otherCondition: 1,
   status,
}
```

When the status is `undefined`, it generates

```
{
   otherCondition: 1,
   status: "undefined",
}
```

Comment: You can play with named props: `x = { [ y ? 'y' : undefined]: y }`, but it will still populate `'undefined': status` prop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) with [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
...status && { status }
```

If `status` is a falsy value, the evaluated expression won't "return" object, and spread will ignore it. If it's a truty value, the short circuit will "return" the `{ status }` object, and the spread will work in the normal way:

**Falsy**

```js
const {status} = {};

const query = {
   otherCondition: 1,
   ...status && { status }
};

console.log(query);
```

**Truthy**

```js
const {status} = { status: 5 };

const query = {
   otherCondition: 1,
   ...status && { status }
};

console.log(query);
```

Comment: It looks like any Booleans, Numbers, Null and Undefined are ignored, no matter their values.

Comment: Wow, Awesome @Ori. This is what I expected, exactly solving my problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
const status = null;
{
   otherCondition: 1,
   status: (status) ? status: false,
}
```

this will return

```
{
   otherCondition: 1,
   status: false,
}
```

Comment: No, this will not work me. Consider, the object I form will be passed to Mongo `find()` so it will match `status: false`, which is wrong